# Data purging Delete statement formation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-delete

I was just writing a stored procedure and I am stuck badly at one point.

Basically my stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DELETEGUIDTESTNEW1]
     (@IpApplicationNumber NVARCHAR(50) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ApplicationNumber NVARCHAR(20)

    SET @ApplicationNumber = (SELECT APPLICATIONNUMBER 
                              FROM CUSTOMERROLE  
                              WHERE CUSTOMERNUMBER = @IpCustomerNumber 
                                AND CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER = @IpCustomerVersion)

    -- In between I am doing business operation--------------------

    INSERT INTO dbo.DeleteTest1(Statements)
    VALUES ('Delete from '+@GuidTableName+' where ApplicationNumber =' + @ApplicationNumber)
```

I will get my parameter at runtime but actual issue is I want to form my delete statements before getting application number and I want form my delete statements in such a way that when I will get my application number I will fetch all delete statement from table and replace `@ApplicationNumber` by actual application number and will delete records from database.

So basically I want to form delete statements with application number as template and delete records at runtime.

Please help!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Using SPs or parameterised queries enables SQL Server to re-use the same execution plan.  If you use string functions to create a DELETE statement with the @applicationNumber already embedded, SQL Server has to compile a new execution plan *every single time*.  Not to mention the risk of a variation of SQL Injection Attacks  *(Any user able to write to that table of SQL Statements will be able to do almost anything)*.  What are you trying to do an Why?  It feels like you're struggling to do something you should even be trying to do...

Comment: What are you trying to do an Why?     Ok so my delete script will be executed only once at build time and at build time I am creating the delete script with templated application number with delete hierarchy..      Why I am doing it :- I want to implement data purging for my application. I want to delete each and every row from database which is related to my application number...

Comment: I will have a windows scheduler which will identify which application number to be deleted depend upon certain criteria and once it meets that criteria it will send me that application number which I will use to purge my data...

Comment: Why not just have the list of IDs in a table and have a single delete statement that joins all matching rows in a single execution?

Comment: 1) Delete from APPLICATIONPACK where CustomerNumber 
         =@ApplicationNumber and CustomerVersionNumber = 
        @CustomerVersionNumber                                                                       
  
  2) Delete from ADDRESS where AddressGuid=Select AddressGuid FROM APPLICATIONPACK WHERE CustomerNumber = CustomerNumber AND Customerversionnumber = CustomerVersionNumber AND AddressGuid IS NOT NULL

Comment: I am using Id's as you mentioned but the problem is above condition Point 1 can be deleted easily but in point 2 I get actual value of GUID @ runtime and thats why I cant delete first table until and unless I dont have addressguid stored somewhere. because if i delete my first line then I wont find addressguid at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found solution to db purging. To handle runtime GUID situation I published stored procedure from stored procedure.

```
SELECT  @GuidPrimaryTableSpace = @GuidPrimaryTableSpace + DeleteGuidStatement + ';'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM ##Purge_GuidForeignKeyTablePurgeStatements

SELECT @GuidForeignKeyTableSpace = @GuidForeignKeyTableSpace +'Insert Into @AddressRecordsToPurge (GuidValue, GuidColumn) ( '+ SelectGuidStatement +');'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)     
FROM ##Purge_GuidPrimaryTablePurgeStatements 

SELECT @DeleteGuidStatementSpace = @DeleteGuidStatementSpace + DeleteGuidValueStatement + ';'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM ##Purge_GuidTableNames

SET @createProcedureCmd = 'CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc' + ' (@ApplicationNum nvarchar(50),@CustomerNumber nvarchar(50),@CustomerVersionNumber nvarchar(50)) AS ' + ' BEGIN  '+    
   ' DECLARE @ApplicationNumber nvarchar(50); SET @ApplicationNumber = @ApplicationNum;

        DECLARE @AddressRecordsToPurge TABLE
        (
        RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        GUIDValue Nvarchar(max),
        GUIDColumn Nvarchar(max)
        )'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @GuidForeignKeyTableSpace +  @GuidPrimaryTableSpace + @DeleteGuidStatementSpace +' END'

        EXEC(@createProcedureCmd)
```

So here I am forming all select statement first and publishing stored procedure. At runtime when it will hit my published stored procedure, I will first find all guids in temp table and then start my delete.

Thank you anyways for all inputs.